# Can I read a small txt file on the main thread or should I ALWAYS avoid I/O there?

Tags: android, multithreading

I am reading a small .json file with a couple of lines in it. It is stored on the user's device in the internal app folder.

all I do is this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(MyUtils.inputStreamToString(MyUtils.fileToFileInputStream(context.getFileStreamPath("last_update.json"))));
        dateOfLastUpdate = jsonObject.getString("lastUpdate");
```

At the moment I've wrapped an async task around it.

What if I remove the async task and run this on the main UI thread?

Should we ALWAYS async ALL I/O operations?

Comment: Why change it, if you have it in an AsynTask already?

Comment: Always. The *only* exception - if you need to read the file as part of the startup (and you show no UI until it's done). Consider if there's a problem with the FS for some reason - you want a "loading" animation to play, not just the entire thing frozen, right? Also consider what happens when you move that file to the cloud - that's suddenly network IO, that *needs* to be outside the main thread. Would you rather hunt down each invocation, or just change the location?

Comment: good point. if you provide this as the answer, I'd accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should *always* use async operations for I/O.

The only reasonable exception I can think about - is when you have some kind of configuration/key file that you need to read before showing **any** type of UI.

Consider these arguments in support of `AsyncTask`:

- What happens if there is a problem with the FS? I imagine you would want a "Loading.." animation to play, with, possibly an option to cancel? In case of main-thread access you will just have a app freeze.
- You currently have only the "lastUpdate" field in your file, hence it's small, and it may be tempting to read it directly (takes no time at all). Do your co-developers know it has to remain small? Are you enforcing it somehow? Small "just one line to store" files have the tendency to grow into huge configuration files with time. It's better to just make access async now, since it doesn't tax you to do so.
- Consider what happens if you change the storage medium. It's on the FS now, maybe you'll have to move it to the cloud in the future? Or the new Android comes with special "slower but cheaper" long-term storage? Would you rather be sure that it still "just works", or hunt down every invocation in your app to make sure they're all async and won't fail in runtime?

All in all - leaving it as an async task doesn't hurt you - but protects against a lot of potential headaches in the future.