# DO we need any thread to perform File operations in android?

Tags: android

I do read and write operations in my android project for JSON data.I would like to know should we want to use any thread to perform File operations.If no, why it is not neccessary?

Comment: If you're doing any network or IO operations, it always advised to offload it to a new thread rather than doing it on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes, you should always use async operations for `I/O`.
>
> The only reasonable exception I can think about - is when you have
>   some kind of configuration/key file that you need to read before
>   showing any type of UI.

Refer this:
[Aync Usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27068122/3505534)

Answer (score 0):

No. You dont need to use a thread for IO.

If you just try you will soon see that threads are not needed.

But if the operation takes long your GUI becomes not responsive.

For that you will use a thread.

Determine yourself how long an operation can take before it gets annoying for the user of your app.